# Remove a random expression from string

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle, substr

I have a string/column something like this

```
String a = "000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W x3A 973911_2012-12-22.PDF";
```

I want to create a substring which doesn't have the part `' x3A 973911'` in it.

Whic means I want something like this,

```
000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22.PDF
```

There is a list of such strings which will have different values but the format will be the same.   I want the part of string to be removed which comes after the first space and ends at the next '_'.

This is what I have done already, this is working fine, but want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

```
String b = a.replaceAll(a.substring(a.indexOf(" "), a.indexOf("_",a.indexOf(" "))),"");
```

It would be even better if I can do this in db itself, which is oracle, instead of in java. Any idea to get this formatted string from the column directly using select?

One more requirement, I dont want to display the extension of the file. 
So nothing after the '.' should be displayed, which means something like this `'000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22'` 
I tried the following using the previous solution of APC

```
 select regexp_replace ( your_string
                          , '([^[:space]]*) (.*)_(.*)....'
                          , '\1_\3') as new_string from your_table
```

This is working fine for now.
This should be removing last 4 characters and have the risk of not getting proper result if the extension is more or less than 3 or if the string is not truncated. 
 I'm looking for a more aesthetic way to do it.
Any chance?

Comment: Ok. I decided on doing this in query itself. All I need now is the regex to use in REGEXP_REPLACE sql function. Any help please?

Comment: My solution should now work for you - unless you have any more wrinkles up your sleeve ;)

Comment: I need one more help, I dont want to display the extension of the file. so nothing after the '.' should be displayed, which means something like this '000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22'. Any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in the database:

```
select regexp_replace ( your_string
                         , '([^[:space]]*) (.*)_(.*)'
                         , '\1_\3') as new_string
from your_table
```

---

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't have any syntax to enforce laziness (non-greediness) in its regex implementation.  That's why my original '(.*) ' included the `x3A`: it matched up to the last space with a following underscore.  However, the negation syntax will isolate the string up to the first space.

> "The '_' after W is missing. Any chance to get that also?"

You can format the replacement string anyway you want.  The easy way out is to do what I have done, and hardcode the underscore between the two matched patterns.  Alternatively you could make it a search pattern in its own right and include it in the replacement string (although you're more more likley to do that for more complicated searches).

---

Oracle introduced Regular Expressions in 10g; the functions are covered [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#sthref918).  The regex implementation is POSIX compliant, so it lacks some of the functions you might have come across in say Perl.  The Regex support is detailed in [an appendix to the SQL ref.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix.htm#i691974)

As for tutorials, well I have a much-thumbed copy of the O'Reilly pocket book; I was given my copy at Open World 2003 but the ebook is reasonably priced.  [Buy it here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006013.do).  Anotgher good starting point is a series of threads by `cd` on the OTN forum: [start reading here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=427716&tstart=0).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the extra spaces in the text.  Try my revised code.

Comment: Its giving me this 000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W2012-12-22.PDF but I wanted 000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22.PDF. The '_' after W is missing. Any chance to get that also? Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any tutorial or link where I can learn about the regex in sql?

Comment: I need one more help, I dont want to display the extension of the file. so nothing after the '.' should be displayed, which means something like this '000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22'. Any chance?

Answer (score 4):

```
final String r = a.replaceAll(" .*?(?=_)", "");
```

if you print the r, it gave output:

```
000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22.PDF
```

Comment: Wow.. Good one. I wish this site has a 'like' button like in facebook :)

Comment: @jijo It actually has 2 'like' buttons: you can upvote answers you like and you can accept an answer to your own question.

Comment: @jijo the regex in the answer is supported by java. there is look-ahead `(?=_)`  I use oracle as DB in work as well, however I am not an expert in that field. You could check if look-ahead is supported by oracle, if yes, what is the syntax.  If you do the replacement in java, the line in my answer should give what you want.

Comment: Oracle's regexes do have lookahead but this particular regex won't work in Oracle because you can't make a particular expression non-greedy in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a SQL solution, this will update the rows:

```
update yourtable
set field = substr(field, 0, instr(field, ' ')-1) || substr(field, instr(field, '_', instr(field, ' ')))
;
```

and this will just show the converted value:

```
select
  yourtable.field,
  case
    when instr(field, '_', instr(field, ' '))>instr(field, ' ')
    then substr(field, 0, instr(field, ' ')-1) || substr(field, instr(field, '_', instr(field, ' ')))
    else field
  end as new_field
from
  yourtable
```

Comment: I don't want an update table since the original value is needed elsewhere. I need is a select statement

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` takes a regex as an argument, if the substring contains regex markers (such as `[`, `+` for example) you will get an unexpected behaviour.

You can use `replace` instead which does the same thing but takes a string as a parameter.

Apart from that, if you know that you will have a space and a `_` as delimiters, AND the substring in between does not occur elsewhere, then your approach looks fine. You could possibly make it slightly more readable with intermediate variables:

```
int start = a.indexOf(" ");
int end = a.indexOf("_", start);
String b = a.substring(0, start) + a.substring(end, a.length());
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to do it in sql when I retrieve the value from db itself?

Comment: @jijo Oracle plsql has a [replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) function that would probably enable you to do it.

Comment: @jijo `select instr('ABC','B') from dual;` will return 2 (i.e. performs an indexOf). But if you are to do that replacement in a query, a regex will probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Regex issues in the code you provided, i found it less readable also.

Try following:

```
int f = a.indexOf(" ");
int l = a.lastIndexOf("_");
a = a.substring(0,f+1) + a.substring(l+1, a.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace REGEX_REPLACE function.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions115.htm#SQLRF06302

Answer (score 0):

The Java solution given by @Kent above is very elegant and I recommend it. That said, if you want to accomplish this using Oracle's regex engine, you might try the following:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT '000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W x3A 973911_2012-12-22.PDF' AS filename
      FROM dual
)
SELECT filename, REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, ' [^_]*', '')
  FROM t1
```