# Remove a random expression from column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, substr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove a random expression from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100168/remove-a-random-expression-from-string)

I have a column which contains values like this

```
 "000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W x3A 973911_2012-12-22.PDF";
```

I want to create a substring which doesn't have the part `x3A 973911` in it.

Whic means I want something like this,

```
000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W_2012-12-22.PDF
```

The value `x3A 973911` is not constant, so basically, in words, I want the part of string to be removed which comes after the first space and ends at the next '_'.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.  If none of the **four** answers you have had on your other post have been satisfactory, you should edit *that* question to expalin why those answers are not right, giving additional details as necessary.

Comment: I added this with an oracle tag, so that I would get a sql solution, because the previous question had too much java in it which might confuse hardcore sql developers.

Comment: But in your original question you asked for a DB solution, which you now have.

Comment: Ok. But how do I delete this post now?

Answer (score 1):

```
 String phrase="000003023_AggregateStopLossLimit_W x3A 973911_2012-12-22.PDF";
 phrase.replace("x3A 973911","");
```

//am not sure if you have to trim() but i guess this will answer your question.